# Synchronized scrolling of multiple custom views

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, custom-view

I've got custom view, which draws a scale and handles touch event (horizontall scroll of that scale). Drawing part:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    startingPoint = mainPoint;
    counter = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while (startingPoint <= scaleWidth) {
        if(i % 4 == 0) {
            size = scaleHeight / 4;

            if (counter < 24) {
                counter = counter + 1;
            } else {
                counter = 1;
            }

            String c = Integer.toString(counter);
            canvas.drawText(c, startingPoint, endPoint - (size + 20), textPaint);

        } else {
            if(i % 2 == 0) {
                size = scaleHeight / 8;
            } else {
                size = scaleHeight / 16;
            }
        }

        if(startingPoint >= closest) {
            //метки шкалы
            canvas.drawLine(startingPoint, endPoint - size, startingPoint, endPoint, rulerPaint);

        }

        startingPoint = startingPoint + pxmm;

        i = i + 1;


    }
}
```

And TouchEvent:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            float x = event.getX();
            prevx = x;
            System.out.println(x);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            float z = event.getX();
            float dist = z - prevx;
            mainPoint = prevsp + dist;
            closest = mainPoint - ((int)(mainPoint / pxmm)) * pxmm;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            float y = event.getX();
            prevsp = mainPoint;
            break;
    }

    invalidate();

    return true;
}
```

In activity_main.xml i paste two copies of this view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center|top">

<net.manualuser.calibr.TimeScale
    android:id="@+id/my_scale"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />

<net.manualuser.calibr.TimeScale
    android:id="@+id/my_scale1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

What should i do to synchronize these two views so that when i scroll either scale another one moves simultaneously. If i'm correct i need to set OnTouchListener for my custom views in MainActivity:

```
TimeScale defScale = (TimeScale)findViewById(R.id.my_scale);
TimeScale defScale1 = (TimeScale)findViewById(R.id.my_scale1);
defScale.setOnTouchListener(this);
defScale1.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

And write some code to synchronize them in onTouch method (in MainActivity). But i have now idea how do i do it?

Comment: in onTouchListener you can try simply to pass the event to the other view's `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`. Also you should return false in onTouch of onTouchListener

Comment: @VladMatvienko thx a lot. I should have paid more attention to MotionEvent. When i searched for "pass event to another view" i've got some answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get it working i need to pass event to both of my views in onTouch in MainActivity:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
    defScale.onTouchEvent(event);
    defScale1.onTouchEvent(event);
    return false;
}
```